# Работа с двумерной графикой в java

Tags: java, graphics

При попытке использовать класс Graphics2D, NetBeans предлагает реализовать абстрактные методы из этого класса, как сделать так, что бы методы не реализовывать, а сразу получить возможность рендерить объекты ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наследуешь JPanel, перекрываешь метод paint(Graphics g) и меняешь тип g:

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

объект graphics преобразуется в graphics2d